# Is it possible to make an option of a select dropdown appear as optgroup via css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xml, optgroup

I am actually populating options from xml for my dropdown and Now adding an optgroup to select is a challenge. Can I add them manually and change the behaviour via css

Comment: JavaScript is for behaviour; CSS for presentation.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want, keeping in mind that no one else really knows what you're doing? Code sample or [demo](http://jsfiddle.net) maybe? It *sounds* like you really need a solution to the original problem, not a CSS/JS hack to work around it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch : I have set up a fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/uAhC2/5/   Actually I am not sure how to set up xml at fiddle, so kinda it doesn't work on fiddle but on my local machine it does. I want the dropdown to have optgroup tags as well. Do I need to change the xml or would you suggest putting it locally in html, I would ideally like to have it in xml. Thanks for offering to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add options and optgroups to the select box manually after the fact with jQuery. Assuming your HTML is already available, you could do something like this:

```
$("select").append("<optgroup label='Example'><option>Test1 </option> <option>Test 2</option></optgroup>")
```

If you already have options in the select element, then it would just be a matter of finding all of those options that you would like to group up (via a class name or value attribute, perhaps), then pushing them into a newly create optgroup, then appending the optgroup into the select. Example:

```
var optionsToGroup = $("option.groupthis");
var optGroup = $("<optgroup></optgroup>").append(optionsToGroup);
$('select').append(optGroup);
```

Edit: Based on the Fiddle you've provided, I modified your jQuery code to build the optgroup before the options. This isn't the most efficient way, but it should get you started based on what you've provided. See http://jsfiddle.net/xUJZj

```
var title = $(this).find('title').text();
var optgrouping = "<optgroup label='"+title+"'></optgroup>";
var options = [];
$(this).find('value').each(function(){
          var value = $(this).text();
          options.push("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
 });
  var grouping = $(optgroupting).html(options.join(''));
  select.append(grouping);
```

Edit 2: I've modified the JSFiddle to use an actual XML doc (similar to what you provided). See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/xUJZj/13/
Or, the relevant modified code is here below:

```
function createSelect(xml)
{
                var select = $('#mySelect');
                $(xml).find('menuitem').each(function(){
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    var optgrouping = "<optgroup label='"+title+"'></optgroup>";
                    var options = [];
                    $(this).find('value').each(function(){
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        options.push("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
                    });
                    var group = $(optgroupting).html(options.join(''));
                    select.append(group);
                });
                select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").prop("selected",true);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you refer to this fiddle and help: My options are coming from xml and not manual as how you are saying:
http://jsfiddle.net/uAhC2/5/

Comment: I've fixed the fiddle so that it actually works with the XML you've provided. Let me know if this was what you were looking for.